# Strongly typed searchable html helper using Kendo combobox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, combobox, asp.net-web-api2, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have created a custom html helper using Kendo combobox and used a WebApi to implement server side filtering, the objective is to create a searchable control for a particular entity type,

My entity -

```
public class Resources{
        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

My current html helper -

```
public static MvcHtmlString Searchbox(this HtmlHelper helper, string Name)
    {
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);

        var combo = helper.Kendo().ComboBox();
        combo.Name(Name);
        combo.Filter(FilterType.Contains);
        combo.Suggest(true);
        combo.AutoBind(false);
        combo.DataValueField("Id");
        combo.DataTextField("DisplayName");
        combo.Enable(Enabled);
        combo.MinLength(1);

        combo.DataSource(source => source
            .Read(read => read.Url(urlHelper.HttpRouteUrl("SearchRoute")))
            .ServerFiltering(true)
        );

        return MvcHtmlString.Create(combo.ToHtmlString());
    }
```

I need to make this strongly typed, ie. create a SearchBoxFor(...) helper. Here's what I've tried -

```
public static MvcHtmlString SearchboxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
            Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
            var name = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);

            var expressionResult = expression.Compile();
            var value = expressionResult(htmlHelper.ViewData.Model);

            var combo = htmlHelper.Kendo().ComboBox();
            combo.Name(name);
            combo.Filter(FilterType.Contains);
            combo.Suggest(true);
            combo.AutoBind(false);
            combo.DataValueField("Id");
            combo.DataTextField("DisplayName");
            combo.Enable(Enabled);
            combo.MinLength(1);

            combo.Value((value as Resources).DisplayName);

            combo.DataSource(source => source
                .Read(read => read.Url(urlHelper.HttpRouteUrl("SearchRoute")))
                .ServerFiltering(true)
            );

            return MvcHtmlString.Create(combo.ToHtmlString());
}
```

Problem is the combo-box's items aren't populated until the user actually starts typing in some characters, so when the page loads, the model's property value cannot be pre-populated, so I'm not sure how to implement this.

I tried setting the combo's value to the DisplayName property of the model's property, but even though the text appears, it isn't a valid Resource entity.

I hope all of that made sense